# Routing a subnet into a VPN tunnel

Tags: networking, router, vpn, routing, iptables

I've got a OpenVPN connection between 1 datacenter and another.

The first subnet is `192.168.160.0 with netmask 255.255.240.0`
the other is `10.0.100.1 with netmask 255.255.255.224`

on the 10.x subnet, I **can access** everything from the first subnet with this routing

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         147.75.80.216   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0
10.0.0.0        10.80.120.128   255.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 bond0
10.0.99.0       10.0.99.2       255.255.255.240 UG    0      0        0 tun1
10.0.99.2       *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun1
10.0.100.0      *               255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 virbr1
10.80.120.128   *               255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 bond0
147.75.80.216   *               255.255.255.254 U     0      0        0 bond0
192.168.122.0   *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
192.168.159.0   192.168.159.9   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.159.9   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.160.0   192.168.159.9   255.255.240.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0`

with

`tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.159.10  P-t-P:192.168.159.9  Mask:255.255.255.255
          inet6 addr: fe80::3530:8c84:ccc7:9b6d/64 Scope:Link`

---

On the 192.x subnet, I **cannot access** 10.0.100.1, I have this routing table:

`Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         vlan218-gw.usdc 0.0.0.0         UG    100    0        0 eth0
10.0.100.0      192.168.159.10  255.255.255.224 UG    0      0        0 tun0
localnet        *               255.255.255.240 U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.159.0   192.168.159.2   255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.159.2   *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.159.10  *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.160.0   *               255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 eth1`

with

`tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
          inet addr:192.168.159.1  P-t-P:192.168.159.2  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1`

I can ping 192.168.159.10 successfully and reach the 10.x network (checked with tcpdump), but can't ping anything like 10.0.100.x

Do I need to use iptables, is my routing incorrect?